# How to properly format sql json as desired

Tags: php, json, string, replace, format

Basically,I want to fetch data from mysql and format it into json like this:

```
[
  [
    "title" => "first",
    "uploader" => "root"

  ],
  [
    "title" => "first",
    "uploader" => "root"
  ],
  [
    "title" => "first",
    "uploader" => "root"
  ],
  [
    "title" => "first",
    "uploader" => "root"
  ],
  [
    "title" => "first",
    "uploader" => "root"
  ],
  [
    "title" => "first",
    "uploader" => "root"
  ],
   [
    "title" => "first",
    "uploader" => "root"
  ],
  [
    "title" => "first",
    "uploader" => "root"
  ],
  [
    "title" => "first",
    "uploader" => "root"
  ],
   [
    "title" => "first",
    "uploader" => "root"
  ],

]
```

I used this code:

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

            $query = $_GET['q'];
            if ($query==null) {
                exit('No query');
            }

$sql = "SELECT title,uploader FROM `uploads_public` WHERE Title =:query ";

        if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bindParam(":query", $query, PDO::PARAM_STR);




            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
               echo "Your search $query has the following results(normal json):<br>";
               $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
               $json = json_encode($results);
               echo($json).'<br>';

               echo "While it has the following results when replaced<br>";
               echo  str_replace('}',']',str_replace(':','=>',str_replace('{', '[', "$json")));





         } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later. <br>"; print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
            }
                    // Close statement
        unset($stmt);
        unset($pdo);
        }





   else{
    echo "No input";
}
```

But rather than what I wanted(mentioned above),i got this:

[["title"=>"first","uploader"=>"root"],["title"=>"first","uploader"=>"root"],["title"=>"first","uploader"=>"root"],["title"=>"first","uploader"=>"root"],["title"=>"first","uploader"=>"root"],["title"=>"first","uploader"=>"root"],["title"=>"first","uploader"=>"root"],["title"=>"first","uploader"=>"root"],["title"=>"first","uploader"=>"root"]]

It looks ok,but the major problem is that I don't want all the results compressed together ,I want it exactly the way mentioned..with line breaks(new lines) after every ..`[`,`",` and so on

Thanks

Comment: are u looking for `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`?? but why u need?

Comment: All programs will understand this output.

Comment: @u_mulder really?

Comment: @u_mulder really?

Comment: Try and tell us.

Comment: u_mulder: is right, but u still need as u asked, try like `json_encode($results,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Comment: @u_mulder tell us what

Comment: Indented JSON is nice for **human eyes**. Minimised JSON (AKA 1 line, no `\n`) is great for bandwith and can be deserialized as is.

Comment: @devpro That is what I needed thanks

Comment: @Cid i know but I need it like that for testing..for now...When I'm done I will correct it.Thanks

Comment: glad to help u.

Comment: by the way, `[["title"=>"first","uploader"=>"root"] ... ]` is **invalid** JSON

Comment: @cid Oh I don't really mean json I mean php json....I don't know what I'm talking about now please help

Comment: there is no *"php json"*. Do you mean php array?

Comment: You may already have what you wanted. is the output of `var_dump($result);` (just after `$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`) what you want?

Comment: @Cid so I have been wasting my time all these while?

Comment: Nope, you've certainly learn how to use `json_encode()` and maybe `str_replace()` too. They will help you a lot in programming. There is no waste of time

Comment: @Cid Thanks.You could post an answer so that I could accept it

Comment: No thanks, that's kind anyway :)